# Thus the decomposition of algebraic sets into irreducible ones corresponds to writing a radical ideal as an intersection of prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I read this assertion in Irena Swanson's Thesis:$\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\qquad$ $\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$"In the standard correspondence between algebraic sets and
ideals, algebraic sets correspond to radical ideals and irreducible algebraic sets correspond
to prime ideals. Thus the decomposition of algebraic sets into irreducible ones corresponds
to writing a radical ideal as an intersection of prime ideals."  Why?

Comment: Do you know what this correspondance between radical ideals and algebraic sets is ?

Comment: And do you know that $V(I\cap J) = V(I)\cup V(J)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I know it.